# Making links an active URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, link-to

I currently have a user input a URL link, which is stored inside `content`.

When I display the given page, the links are highlighted similar to a link, but do not actually redirect the user to the URL.

Is there any helper method available in Ruby that can do this?

```
<% @microposts.each do |micropost| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= url_for link_to micropost.content,  %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just showing the link. If you want to *make* a link:

```
<td><%= link_to('link', url_for(micropost.content)) %></td>
```

Comment: Great! Accept the answer if it worked for you so others can find it.